# Display math formulas on android device

Tags: php, android

I am creating one school application. Which have mainly 2 version, one for server side and another for android device. Now I have to add mathematical formulas from server side and i need to show them on android device. I am using fckeditor for question insertion on server side in this i have added formulas from "http://www.codecogs.com/latex/integration/fckeditor/install.php". But i am finding any solution to show them on android device.

So, i am looking for some better way to show/insert math formulas...

Comment: possible soln of ur prob 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701061/math-formulas-on-textview-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know  android device support or not see http://www.mathjax.org/ is a JavaScript program that is for math formula  demo: http://www.mathjax.org/demos/mathml-samples/

Comment: you can add mathjax  as module for  fck editor both written by javaScript

Comment: I have tried using MathJax in android it displays the basic second degree equation quite well but when I try for integration equation i am unable to do so.. please help

Comment: @chinmayghag What is your version of Android?

Comment: its above 4.4. Currently I am trying it on Lolipop

Answer (score 1):

You query the Formulas for server from your android device and Send response as JSON data or XML data to the Android device. Parse the JSON or XML in your Android Client. Then Show it in the device as you wish.

THere are lot of JSON/XML parsers available for parsing them.

Answer (score 0):

I already worked   on same type of App . My App was based RestFull Architecture and in my App Communication  going on , in the form of JSON object from client to server. I hope this suggestion will help you