# Math formulas on textview in android

Tags: android, math

I am working on an app in which i have to set Math Formulas on a textView which are coming from web.
eg: i wanna set Quadratic formula as it present on kids textbook.

Comment: Cool. And your question is? You tried what? Your problem is?

Comment: @StefandeBruijn i got my solution

Comment: @SaurabhAndroid Hello saurabh, I am facing same issue with my application, I have to insert math formulas from web and need to display on my android device then how do i display it.. ?

Comment: @VishalParekh did you check my answer?

Comment: Yes i checked it ... but i am confuse to integrate it with php fck-editor. I have insert data from php side in fck editor and need to show them in android device. So my problem is integrate Mathjax with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use MathJax**

[Sample android here](http://cs.jsu.edu/wordpress/?p=498)

Comment: It is certainly not working for integartion equations